# Using defineClass to Dynamically Create Class from Bytes

Tags: java, noclassdeffounderror, urlclassloader

It seems like I should be able to do this with a class loader derived from `URLClassLoader` that includes a `loadClass()`:

```
public Class loadClass(String className, byte[] classBytes)
throws ClassNotFoundException, NoClassDefFoundError
{
    Class result = null;

    result = defineClass(className, classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
    classes.put(className, result);
    return result;
}
```

Then I read bytes from a class file and call the above loadClass method.  I get this:

`java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/samples/SampleClass (wrong name: com/samples/SampleClass)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:465)`

The odd thing is that the name and the "wrong name" are the same.  And both are the correct package.

How is it possible to get `NoClassDefFoundError` with the correct expected name?
And is it possible to do this `defineClass`?

Using the deprecated form, without the classname, works perfectly:

```
result = defineClass(classBytes, 0, classBytes.length);
```

Thanks

Comment: How come your className is com/samples/SampleClass instead of com.samples.SampleClass? In your case classname is invalid (which is stated correctly in exception)

Answer (score 1):

javadoc:
Parameters:
name - The expected name of the class, or null if not known, using '.' and not '/' as the separator and without a trailing ".class" suffix.

try replace "/" to "."